# Float Left Spacing

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've got a collection of points that I'm displaying, I'm floating them all left, but if the text is too much in the one above it forces there to be a space appear. Can't figure out what's causing this, does anyone have any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="all-the-screen checkmark-move">
        <div class="contain-inner">
            <div class="checkmark-outer">

                <div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Water Included</div></div>
                <div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Gas Included</div></div>
                <div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Electric Included</div></div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="read-more-show noselect">Show More</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.checkmark-outer {
    width:92%;
    margin-left:4%;
    margin-right:4%;
}
.checkmark-move {
    margin-top:18px;
}
.checkmark-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro Regular';
    line-height:24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:4px;
}
.checkmark-33 {
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:6px;
}
.checkmark-icon {
    float:left;
}
.icon-background {
    color: #8d1e22;
}

.icon-text {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Problem getting
[image]

Comment: `<div class="clearfix"></div>` Where have you defined this class?

Comment: `.clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}`

Comment: If that's the case, you need to use it for the three checkmarks.

Comment: Don't give height. Use the clearfix properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, since you are already familiar with the `clearfix` concept, you are using it wrong. Change your code this way, to include the `float`ed elements inside the `.clearfix`:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Water Included</div></div>
  <div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Gas Included</div></div>
  <div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Electric Included</div></div>
</div>
```

Adding `height` is a hacky way. Use the `clearfix` properly to nest the floated items.

And also on a side note, use `<i>` tag to display icons and not `<div>` tags. It works, but it is not semantically correct. A `<div>` should be used only for a division or a section.

Comment: @CameronMarkLewis You are welcome. `:)` I believe it would be always better to wait, understand the problem and correct the root cause, than to give a hackjob suggestions.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Can you help me how your solution is working Here is your way: https://jsfiddle.net/kkbjeggc/

Comment: @Master.Deep Where exactly is the `.clearfix` definition? And you haven't used it the right way.

Comment: Update with clearfix. Although I was unaware that you need Bootstrap to be mandatory. Well still no fix. I hope I have followed each and every step you have provided in your solution if not then please tell me what I haven't followed i.e mentioned by you in your answer

Comment: @Master.Deep This is a simple explanation for you: http://jsbin.com/mosawiwawa/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Give `min-height` to each checkmark wrap i.e in your case `.checkmark-33`

Example-

```
.checkmark-33{min-height:50px /*This should be the max-height of your longest checkmark*/}
```

Comment: Hey! If I do this, it only moves down the Close to Main Bus Station and Close to Supermarkets... The rest stay inline?

Comment: If you added height then if in case there will text overflow then text would be overhidden

Comment: You can't keep checking the height for every element, right? `:)` This solution is a hack-job. Concentrate on the problem, not on getting the solution, please.

Comment: in that case then how would anyone can give height to an element. Cause there also you need an approx idea of max-height of the checkmark. Otherwise in most of the checkmark text will be half visible

Comment: @Master.Deep Check out my answer for the right way buddy.

Comment: @Praveen Doesn't think too static. If you got a long list of data. we cant insert clearfix in between that make the code dirty. And as you said concentrate on problem then thinking problem in broader term not in too narrow way, then we have to make the layout better as well as give user the useful information. Your code may give the right layout but second option will not get fulfilled

Comment: @Master.Deep Agreed. :)

Comment: Asking for upvotes is frowned upon, plus your answer is wrong. Sorry. :(

Comment: Every guy has its own way of writing their code adding external clearfix is not right as per my opinion may be you have other opinion on this. Their is always multiple solution to 1 question.lets don't make this comments more longer if you need pin me on chat.